# Combo Charts for angular-chart.js

Tags: angularjs, angular-chart

Is it possible to build a combo charts using  http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/?

Comment: It seems that you can do that : http://www.fusioncharts.com/angularjs-charts/#/demos/ex3

Comment: That's right.  So it's not possible for angularjs-charts right?

Comment: If I understand well, a combo chart is a bar chart combined with a graph so the example is fine after removing the area representation. Am I correct ?

Comment: Example a combination of a Bar and a Line in the same chart.

Comment: @potatopeelings answer is fine. The link I shared to you isn't actually angular charts as the title miss guided me. But if you can use fusion charts instead of angular charts, it seems matching your needs.

Comment: Fusion charts are not free right?

Comment: As long as your application isn't a commercial one, you can use fusion charts free.

Comment: Is there a way to define labels font size?

Comment: Yes you can by using attribute `baseFontSize` on the chart tag. You can also specify font and color with `baseFont` and `baseFontColor`.

Answer (score 0):

angular-chart is based on Chart.js v1.0.2 which does not support combo charts.

Note - the new version of Chart.js (v2.0) does support combo charts, but angular-chart does not work with that yet (see https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/issues/123)